# post request in Unirest Java result on a 302 http result

Tags: java, spring, rest, http, unirest

I m training my self on creating a restful server and a desktop java based client.

my backend is Spring Boot based, I have the following controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(NiveauAccessController.URL)
public class NiveauAccessController extends GenericController{

public static final String URL = "/acl";

@Autowired
private NiveauAccessRepository niveauAccessRepository;

@PostMapping
private ServerResponse createACL(
            @RequestParam("aclTitle") final String aclTitle,
            @RequestParam("roles") final List<String> roles 
){
    if(isSessionValid()){
        final MNG_NIVEAU_ACCEE mng_niveau_accee = new MNG_NIVEAU_ACCEE();
        mng_niveau_accee.setAclTitle(aclTitle);
        List<Role> enumRoles = new ArrayList();
        roles.stream().forEach(role->{
            enumRoles.add(Role.valueOf(role));
        });
        mng_niveau_accee.setRoles(enumRoles);
        niveauAccessRepository.save(mng_niveau_accee);
        initSuccessResponse(mng_niveau_accee);
        return serverResponse;
    }
    initFailLoginResponse();
    return serverResponse;
}
.
.
.
}
```

for my java client I m using this sample code to send a post request over my server :

```
@FXML
private void doAdd(ActionEvent event) throws UnirestException {
    if (titleACL.getText().isEmpty()) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        alert.initOwner(((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());
        alert.setContentText("Veuillez remplir le champ");
        alert.showAndWait();
        titleACL.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    String title = titleACL.getText();
    Predicate<? super JFXCheckBox> selectedCheckboxes = checkbox -> {
        return checkbox.isSelected();
    };
    List<JFXCheckBox> selectedCheckBoxesList = observableCheckBoxes.values().stream().filter(selectedCheckboxes).collect(Collectors.toList());
    final List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();
    selectedCheckBoxesList.stream().forEach(checkbox -> {
        roles.add(checkbox.getText());
    });

    HttpResponse<String> asString = Unirest.post(ACL_URL)
            .header("accept", "application/json")
            .field("aclTitle", title)
            .field("roles", roles)
            .asString();

    System.out.println(asString.getStatus());
    System.out.println(asString.getHeaders().values());
    if (asString.getStatus() == 200) {
    }
}
```

my output is :

> 302
>
> [[0], [Thu, 10 May 2018 13:30:05 GMT], [https://localhost:8443/acl]]

I don't understand why I m getting the 302 status code which is for URL redirection.

I m trying to use this post to add data to my database.

What should I do to make my Server accept this request?

Comment: I know that i shouldn't use a repository in a controller but I have to create a service but since I m training my self to do Rest Request properly I m postponing services refactoring for another time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

havins ssl enabled my request over 8080 got redirection to 8443 this is no issue using a web browser because it will handle redirection but in a javafx client you have to handle the redirect by your self so there is a possible solution

```
if (asString.getStatus() == 200) {
      //your success handler code
}else if (asString.getStatus() == 302) {
      // use your Rest api to do the request using the response body
}
```